# Windows 10 how to get into sleep state quickly when there is suspended process

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, power, suspend

I use [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) or [PsSuspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend) to suspend process. When there is no suspended process, Windows get into sleep state completely only seconds after I clicked *sleep* from the power menu, but become minutes when there is suspended process, and during the minutes I can't wake up Windows by tapping power button. How to get Windows 10 sleep quickly even though there is suspended process?

Comment: What is the computer doing during these minutes?

Comment: When Windows is running, the running LED is on. After computer completely get into sleep, the running LED is blinking. During the minutes after I clicked sleep when there is suspended process, the screen is off and the running LED is still on. Whichever button or key I press, the computer responses nothing. After the running LED become blinking, I know the computer is completely slept then I can wake it by power button. @harrymc

Comment: Is there any indication for disk activity ?

Comment: No, there's no disk LED and I didn't hear any sound of HDD, maybe HDD's sound is covered by fans'. There's more detail: if the suspended process is `ffmped.exe` with no child process, computer can get slept very quickly; but if the suspended processes are a set of child processes and their common parent process like `chrome.exe`, it'll take longer to get slept, the more child processes, the longer. In both conditions, there'll **only** be my clicking sleep and the actually falling sleep in system logs. @harrymc

Comment: Does it matter which process is suspended?

Comment: Yes. When suspended process tree is from `chrome.exe` or `WeChat.exe`, even the number of processes are the same, the time it takes to get slept differs a lot.

Comment: Perhaps because the suspended process had open internet connections at the time of the suspend, so Windows needs to wait the keep-alive time of the connection, which is normally 2 minutes, before it can cut close the connection and enter sleep.